# jQuery "Promise" resetting ol bullets to zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html-lists, promise

I am having a problem with a jQuery plugin i am writing and was hoping for some guidance here.

The plugin is just a simple "Accordion". When you click on a heading, other already expanded sections collapse, and the clicked section expands. (i know there are many accordion plugins to download, but consider this an educational exercise for me as well)

Below is my full page code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="collapsibleGroup">
            <div>
                <h3>Heading 1</h3>
                <div class="hiddenContent">
                    <ol>
                        <li>line 1</li>
                        <li>line 2</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Heading 2</h3>
                <div class="hiddenContent">
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script>
            (function($) {
                $.collapse = function( el, options ) {
                    var base = this;

                    base.$el = $(el);

                    base.init = function() {
                        base.$hideable = base.$el.find('.hiddenContent');
                        base.$trigger = base.$el.find('h3');

                        base.$hideable.hide();
                    }

                    base.init();

                    base.$trigger.on('click', function(e){
                        var $clicked = $(this);
                        var isVisible = ($clicked.next('div.hiddenContent').is(':visible')) ? true : false;

                        base.$hideable.slideUp(300);
                        base.$hideable.promise().done(function(){
                            if(!isVisible) {
                                $clicked.next('div.hiddenContent').slideDown(300)
                            }
                        })
                    })
                };

                $.fn.collapse = function(options) {
                    return this.each(function() {
                        (new $.collapse(this, options))
                    })
                }
            })(jQuery);

            $('.collapsibleGroup').collapse();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem - which is only happening in Internet Explorer - is this. If you click "heading 1" you will see it expand, and 2 numbered bullets are shown.  Then click "heading 2" and the first heading will collapse, and the second heading will expand, showing some text.  Now, if you click "heading 1" again, section 2 collapses, section 1 expands, but the numbered bullets are both numbered 0 (zero).

I have no idea why this is happening, but I suspect it has to do with the "promise" function. If i take my slideDown command outside of a promise, this doesn't happen. In reality, my code is larger than this, and the promise is required, so if anyone can shed any light on this subject, I would be grateful.

Many thanks

Comment: You mean when you click on "heading 1" the first time then the bullets are correctly numbered 1 and 2?

Comment: It is probably not the promise, you can try by moving the done callback directly on the [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/#slideUp-duration-easing-complete).

Comment: I am a little confused with this now. I was advised that this was a bug in JQuery, and I should log a bug with them. I did that, and got this response.  "This is a known bug in IE, based on a specific order of DOM operations. You can see that this came up 3 years ago in jQuery UI:  http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6720 and the solution was simply changing the order of the style changes."  In my code, I cannot for the life of me see what I need to re-order to get this to work.  Does anyone else have any idea?

Comment: Could you please also link your own bug report?

Comment: Thanks for your time Bergi, but I decided to come at this from a different approach.  Re-writing the code avoided the problem.

Comment: Still, please [let us know how you solved the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :-)

Comment: Old question know, I could not reproduce the problem on IE9, 10 or 11 (http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/HVUU3/3/) and it will not work at all in IE8 (which that jQuery bug related too). What jQuery version were you using at the time?